Tailwind creating custom plugin but cannot get background color to show
Wanting to create a custom plugin for my project but I cannot get the theme colors to work.  Any help would be appreciated.
Have tried adding the color manually which works but is not ideal to trying to only have to color reference in one place in case it changes.
Project is running Astro JS.
const plugin = require("tailwindcss/plugin");

const button = plugin(
  ({ addUtilities, addComponents, addBase, theme, config }) => {
    addComponents({
      ".button-teal": {
        color: "#FFFFFF",
        backgroundColor: theme("colors.teal"),
      },
    });
  },
);

module.exports = button;

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const colors = require("tailwindcss/colors");
const plugin = require("tailwindcss/plugin");
export default {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      teal: {
        DEFAULT: "#00a7b5",
        dark: "#007482",
      },
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        teal: {
          DEFAULT: "#00a7b5",
          dark: "#007482",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("./src/plugins/CustomUtilities")],
};

Tried changing between addComponents, addBase and addUtilities.  colors.black and colors.white works but no other colors.

It doesn't make sense to have a property value to be an object since that would be invalid CSS. You'd need to pick a scalar JavaScript value to be the value of the CSS property. For example,
colors.teal.DEFAULT:
const plugin = tailwind.plugin;

const button = plugin(
  ({ addUtilities, addComponents, addBase, theme, config }) => {
    addComponents({
      ".button-teal": {
        color: "#FFFFFF",
        backgroundColor: theme("colors.teal.DEFAULT"),
      },
    });
  },
);

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      teal: {
        DEFAULT: "#00a7b5",
        dark: "#007482",
      },
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        teal: {
          DEFAULT: "#00a7b5",
          dark: "#007482",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [button],
};

<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<div class="button-teal">Button</div>

